# How to get value in uitextfield according to the tag id of uitextfield.?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am working with `GMSAutocompleteViewController` where i have three `UITextfield` in my `uiviewcontroller`. When first `UItextfield` is click i move to `GMSAutocompleteViewController` with tag number, but now i want to display place name in textfield which is click by user in `gmsautocompleteviewcontroller` method. Please look at my code.

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


 NSLog(@"start editing");

    if (textField.tag ==1) {
        NSLog(@"first");
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];


       }
    else if (textField.tag ==2)
    {
        NSLog(@"second");
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (textField.tag ==3)
    {
        NSLog(@"third");
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
       }




      }


    - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
      didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    // Do something with the selected place.
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
    NSLog(@"lat and log%f", place.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"lang %f", place.coordinate.longitude);



    value = place.name;


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       }

    - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
    didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    NSLog(@"error: %ld", (long)[error code]);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }

     // User canceled the operation.
     - (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"Autocomplete was cancelled.");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
      }
```

Comment: I want to get place name on that uitextfield which is click by user.?

Comment: you can manage it by checking active textfield...

Comment: value in uitextfield according to the tag id of uitextfield. means with tag you want text of that `UITextField`?

Comment: yes that's right for example if i click textfield with tag value 1 than selected  place  from search bar should be show on that textfield not anyone else.

Comment: @Dev.RK is it possible by checking active textfield?

Comment: Yes manage active textfield and set text to active textfield when user select place name

Comment: Getting Value in TextFieldDidEndEditing Delegate.

Comment: @KiritModi its not working in this case because it shows value when i click some other textfield.

Comment: @Dev.RK can you give some demo code for active textfield please?

Comment: Thanks all of for your kind suggestions, answer by Sherin working correct for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare globally a textfield

```
 UITextField *tappedTextField;
```

check below code

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
tappedTextField = textField;
}
 //gmsautocomplete delegate
 - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
// Do something with the selected place.
NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
NSLog(@"lat and log%f", place.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"lang %f", place.coordinate.longitude);



tappedTextField.text = place.name;


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```